# Delete the contents of a huge directory in CentOS 6.6

Tags: linux, centos6

I have a directory in my webserver that has 116 thousand cookie files in it.

How do I delete them?

```
rm -r /var/www/html/secured/cookies/*
```

I tried this but it does not work.

```
-bash: /bin/rm/: Argument list too long
```

That is the error given.

Comment: `ls -f | xargs rm` will be faster than find. The -f option disables the sort (shell globbing always sorts; ls usually does)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

find /var/www/html/secured/cookies -type f -delete

Or something with xargs, but I prefer the find command..

Comment: That worked a treat. Anyway to set this up as a cron job every 12 hours?

Comment: sure, just put a "* */12 * * * root find /var/www/html/secured/cookies -type f -delete" in /etc/cron.d/deletecookies

Answer (score 1):

Using perl?

```
perl -e 'for(</var/www/html/secured/cookies/*>){unlink}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have hidden (dot) files you want to save, just remove the whole folder

```
rm -r /var/www/html/secured/cookies
```

Then, if needed, recreate it

```
mkdir /var/www/html/secured/cookies
```